# Status Bar Progress Meter not showing messages

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I'm trying to put together a 'Status Bar Progress Meter' to help the user when loading a lengthy macro.

I've carried out some research and found [this](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/show-a-progress-meter-in-the-status-bar/) to be the type that I'd like to use.

The problem I have is that the progress bar doesn't move across the Status Bar and the first and last messages i.e. "Working" and "All Files Extracted" are not shown. Where have I gone wrong?

```
Private Sub btnFetchFiles_Click()

    Dim j As Integer

        iRow = 20
        fPath = "\\c\s\CAF1\Dragon Mentor Group\Dragon Scripts\Current\April 2015"
        If fPath <> "" Then

            ' make StatusBar visible
            Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
            Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
            'First Message
            Application.StatusBar = String(5, ChrW(9609)) & " Working..."
            If FSO.FolderExists(fPath) <> False Then
                'Second Message
                Application.StatusBar = String(5, ChrW(9609)) & " Working..."
                Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(fPath)
                'Third Message
                Application.StatusBar = String(5, ChrW(9609)) & " Working..."
                IsSubFolder = True
                'Fourth Message
                Application.StatusBar = String(5, ChrW(9609)) & " Still Working..."
                Call DeleteRows
                If AllFilesCheckBox.Value = True Then
                'Fifth Message
                Application.StatusBar = String(5, ChrW(9609)) & " Still Working..."
                    Call ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolder, IsSubFolder)
                    Call ResultSorting(xlAscending, "C20")
                    Call FormatCells
                Else
                    Call ListFilesInFolderXtn(SourceFolder, IsSubFolder)
                    Call ResultSorting(xlAscending, "C20")
                    Call FormatCells
                End If
                'Sixth Message
                Application.StatusBar = String(5, ChrW(9609)) & "Still Working..."
                lblFCount.Caption = iRow - 20
                'Seventh Message
                Application.StatusBar = String(5, ChrW(9609)) & "Almost Done..."
            Else
                MsgBox "Selected Path Does Not Exist !!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Select Correct One and Try Again !!"
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Folder Path Can not be Empty !!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & ""
        End If
                'Eigth Message
                Application.StatusBar = String(5, ChrW(9609)) & "All Files Extracted..."
       'Relinquish the StatusBar
        Application.StatusBar = False
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you don't see them is that they are immediately overwritten by the next `StatusBar` message.

Take this for example:

```
   'Eigth Message
   Application.StatusBar = String(5, ChrW(9609)) & "All Files Extracted..."
   'After the previous message has displayed for zero seconds, 
   'Relinquish the StatusBar
   Application.StatusBar = False
```

You're displaying a message and erasing it right away.

Same idea for your first message. The statements that occur in between probably execute in less than a millisecond, so that's how long your first message will show; hence you don't see it. Which, in a way, makes total sense, because there is no need for a progress meter to be displayed if progress is instantaneous.

The example in the [link you provide](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/show-a-progress-meter-in-the-status-bar/) uses `Application.Wait` statements to force the program to wait while the progress bare is being shown. But that's just for illustration purposes; you would never slow down your actual program on purpose like that.

---

The reason the progress bar isn't getting longer and longer is that you are explicitly telling it to stay the same length:

```
String(5, ChrW(9609))
```

will always return a progress bar that is five characters long: `▉▉▉▉▉`. The example in the [link you provide](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/show-a-progress-meter-in-the-status-bar/) makes it grow from 5 to 10 to 15.

Comment: Hi I've been back to my code and changed this so the number increases, but I'm still left with a white back gorund and the text. Kind Regards. Chris

Comment: Hi, thank you for coming back to me with this. I did actually make a note in my original post which said *The problem I have is that the progress bar doesn't move across the Status Bar....*, so I thought this encompassed the problem unless you think another post is still needed. Kind regards. Chris

Comment: I've done my best to answer given the information you provided. Not clear what you mean by "progress bar doesn't move".

Comment: Hi, ok, I'll post another question and take from there. Kind Regards. Chris