# Progress Meter characters not displaying as intended

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I'm trying to implement a 'Status Bar Progress Meter' I've found [here](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/show-a-progress-meter-in-the-status-bar/) and implemented this in my code as below:

```
Private Sub btnFetchFiles_Click()

    Dim j As Integer

        iRow = 20
        fPath = "\\c\s\CAF1\Dragon Mentor Group\Dragon Scripts\Current\April 2015"
        If fPath <> "" Then

            ' make StatusBar visible
            Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
            Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
            'First Message
            Application.StatusBar = String(5, ChrW(9609)) & " Working..."
            If FSO.FolderExists(fPath) <> False Then
                'Second Message
                Application.StatusBar = String(10, ChrW(9609)) & " Working..."
                Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(fPath)
                'Third Message
                Application.StatusBar = String(15, ChrW(9609)) & " Working..."
                IsSubFolder = True
                'Fourth Message
                Application.StatusBar = String(15, ChrW(9609)) & " Still Working..."
                Call DeleteRows
                If AllFilesCheckBox.Value = True Then
                'Fifth Message
                Application.StatusBar = String(15, ChrW(9609)) & " Still Working..."
                    Call ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolder, IsSubFolder)
                    Call ResultSorting(xlAscending, "C20")
                    Call FormatCells
                Else
                    Call ListFilesInFolderXtn(SourceFolder, IsSubFolder)
                    Call ResultSorting(xlAscending, "C20")
                    Call FormatCells
                End If
                'Sixth Message
                Application.StatusBar = String(20, ChrW(9609)) & "Still Working..."
                lblFCount.Caption = iRow - 20
                'Seventh Message
                Application.StatusBar = String(25, ChrW(9609)) & "Almost Done..."
            Else
                MsgBox "Selected Path Does Not Exist !!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Select Correct One and Try Again !!"
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Folder Path Can not be Empty !!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & ""
        End If
                'Eigth Message
                Application.StatusBar = String(30, ChrW(9609)) & "All Files Extracted..."
       'Relinquish the StatusBar
        Application.StatusBar = False
    End Sub
```

You will see in the image below that there is a blue progress meter running from left to right with small rectangles,

[image]

but when I run my script, I'm left not with small rectangles but with a continuous white bar as shown here:

[image]

Why? Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Do you see the "Working..." and "Still working..." etc. or is the whole status bar blank?

Comment: Hi @stucharo, thank you for coming back to me with this. The only message I see is "Still Working", but it has been suggested to me that this may be because the process is so instaneous and that's why I don't see this text. Kind Regards. Chris

Comment: wait a minute, you're not adding any new information to what you just asked in your previous question: [Status Bar Progress Meter not showing messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789439/status-bar-progress-meter-not-showing-messages)

Comment: Hi @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, with respect that's what I was trying to say at the time, but you suggested a new post. The issue is the fact that the blue scrolling markers are not being shown in the 'Status Bar'. Kind Regards.

Comment: What happens when you set breakpoints or step through the code (`Shift` + `F8` in the VBA editor)?  That should let you see the status bar changes slowly as you step through.

Comment: Hi @aucuparia, when I step through the code all of the text messages appear and the 'Status Bar expands in size when it reaches these parts of the code `String(10, ChrW(9609))` with the 10 indicating the number of blocks to display. Kind Regards Chris

Comment: How long does the whole code take to execute? What happens if you put a `DoEvents` after each `StatusBar` statement?

Comment: Hi @Jean-FrançoisCorbett. At the moment this takes about 5 minutes but in the near future more data will be added which will increase the time the data extract takes. I can confirm that I've implemented the `DoEvents` but unfortunately this has no effect. Many thanks and kind regards. Chris

Comment: Why don't you use a userform instead?

Comment: Hi @Rory, thank you for taking the time to come back to me with this. I had though of that, but the problem I have is that we use dual montiors, and I wan't sure how to always make sure that the userform appeared on the screen where the macro was being run. Kind Regards. Chris

Comment: Have you tried changing `ChrW(9609)` to a simple `A`?  It might be that your system represents `ChrW(9609)` differently.  Also, `ChrW(9608)` and `ChrW(9610)` should give you pretty much the same character, do they do anything different?

Comment: Hi @stucharo, thank you for coming back to me with this.I've tried both suggestions and although changing the character to 9611 for example changes the height of the status bar, there is no blue content to this. Kind Regards. Chris

Comment: What colour is it?  `ChrW(9609)` should just return the unicode character that looks like a rectangular block, the blue colour is a property of the statusbar

Comment: Hi @stucharo, I think we may be onto something here. If I look very very closely  Chrw(9609) are definietely white blocks. Kind Regards. chris

Comment: Run it in debug and post a screenshot of what you _do_ see while it's running - that might help us. I just ran it in Excel 2010, and it works just fine. I get a black box on a grey background, and is exactly what I'd expect with the `Silver` color scheme. I changed to the `Blue` color scheme and get dark blue boxes on a light blue background.

Comment: Hi @Freeman, thank you for looking at my post. I'll post the screen shot on return home this evening if that's ok. In terms of the debug screen there is nothing out of the ordinary that happens. The debug works through each line highlighting them in yellow as you would expect. I hope this helps. Kind Regards

Comment: Hi @Freeman, as discussed earlier, I've enclosed the screenshot you asked for in my original post which shows the 'Status Bar' when I run the code through debug or indeed not in debug. Kind Regards. Chris

Comment: Progress bars are cool, but sometimes it's just easier to show a percent complete.

Comment: Well, it does look like the white bar is growing, so it does indicate some change, but it's not as cool as the little blocks.  I've only got _2010_, so I can't help you with the _2013_ issue...  @guitarthrower has a valid point, that may be a better bet in this situation...

Comment: Hi @guitarthrower, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post, and a very worthwhile point.Could you perhaps explain or show me how I may do this please. Many thanks and kind regards. Chris

Comment: Hi @FreeMan, thank you very much for your help it is truly appreciated and as you say a good point from guitarthrower. Kind Regards. Chris

Comment: I get exactly the same as @FreeMan on Excel 2010 and changing themes on Excel 2013 gives white rectangles on variously grey backgrounds.  However, that's not neccessarily a bad thing.....the subsequent unicode characters are rectangles of reducing width so you could make a status bar that grows really smoothly if you added a bit more code around what you have.  Or just set the Statusbar text to a percentage.

Comment: Hi @stucharo, thank you very much for the confirmation, all your help and for the suggestion on the progress bar. Kind regards. Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like, you could replace the bar with a percentage. I typically calculate percentages based on how far through the process the procedure is. In your case you appear to be assigning specific values to your progress, which works as well.

To implement, it would be as simple as replacing this line in your code:

```
Application.StatusBar = String(5, ChrW(9609)) & " Working..."
```

With the following:

```
Application.StatusBar = "Working... 16% complete"
```

(16% because 5/30 from your code).

If you wanted it to be calculated, you could do the following:

```
Application.StatusBar = "Working... " & Round(1 / 6 * 100, 0) & "%"
```

You could replace both `1` and `6` with variables as needed.

Comment: Hi @guitarthrower thank you very much for this. I'll be able to work with this. Kind Regards. Chris

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting blue `▉▉▉▉▉` with a little tiny narrow gap between each rectangle symbol `▉`.

But you're getting white ▉▉▉▉▉ with no gaps.

The answer to "why is this happening" is the following: it's just a different font!

Apparently the Excel 2013 font is white and makes the rectangles a tiny bit wider than the Excel 2010 font such that the gap disappears -- and the rectangles aren't blue but white.

Note that this in no way impedes the functionality of the progress bar. It's just a question of aesthetics and taste — whether you prefer blue or white, [gaps or no gaps](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=tuck+no+tuck&ia=videos&iai=bl3HcIXvIo0).

Comment: Hi @Jean-François Corbett, thank you for coming back to me with this. It's not the gaps that are the issue, they can be seen if I look closely, it's the coloured blocks I'm not getting. They're white rather than blue. Kind Regards Chris

Comment: Same difference! It's just the font!